# How do I call this Postgres function with custom enum input?

Tags: postgresql, function, enums, naming-conventions, identifier

I expected this to be simple, but I've tried multiple combinations and I can't get PostgreSQL to accept them.  It claims there are no matching functions, yet the types listed (as seen in the example below) clearly matches my defined function.

```
                                     List of data types
 Schema |  Name  | Internal name | Size | Elements | Access privileges | Description
--------+--------+---------------+------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | levels | levels        | 4    | debug   +|                   |
        |        |               |      | info    +|                   |
        |        |               |      | warn    +|                   |
        |        |               |      | critical |                   |

CREATE FUNCTION public."logEvent"(IN in_type text,IN in_priority public.levels,IN in_message text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $function$
INSERT INTO public.log (type,priority,message) VALUES (in_type, in_priority, in_message);
$function$;
```

The failing query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM public.logEvent('test'::text,'debug'::public.levels,'test from sql prompt'::text);
ERROR:  function public.logevent(text, levels, text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM public.logEvent('test'::text,'debug'::public.l...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

An alternate function definition: I get the same error when trying to execute this create function call:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."logEvent"(IN in_type text, IN in_priority text, IN in_message text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $function$
SELECT public.logEvent( in_type, CAST(lower(in_priority) AS public.levels), in_message);
$function$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that double-quoted identifiers are case-sensitive?

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

```
CREATE FUNCTION public."logEvent"
```

But:

```
SELECT 1 FROM public.logEvent
```

This should work:

```
SELECT 1 FROM public."logEvent"('test', 'debug', 'test from sql prompt');
```

Explicit type casts are only necessary if there can be ambiguity with overloaded function.

Either keep double-quoting `"logEvent"` for the rest of its existence, or (smarter) use unquoted (effectively lower-case), legal identifiers.

Comment: I was not aware of that (coming from mySQL), but that explains/solves my issue.  The create table syntax was generated by pgAdmin; if I had written it by hand I would have omitted the quotes and likely been even more confused later on ;-)  I'll rename my functions and switch to_the_underscore_naming convention.